# Can HDFS run as native file system of a machine?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was going through a tutorial in which i am using Cloudera VM. The hadoop stack is pre-installed in the VM.
Any time i have to do operation i have to do transfer the file from VM file system to HDFS, it looks to me kind of overhead of copying all the file from native file system (in my case VM native file system) to the HDFS.

```
hdfs dfs -put <FILE_IN_VM_FS> <FILE_IN_HDFS>
```

Does HDFS runs as a native file-system in industrial setting or above mentioned method is the defacto  of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't skip that process with HDFS. Store a file in HDFS imply several steps, like break files in blocks if the file is bigger than the block size, generate records in the namenode to store all metadata related with the file's blocks, create the required replicas, among others. Even you are working with only one node, HDFS was designed to work in a distributed environments.

Comment: Let say in large scale deployment we need  , replica , namnode, breaking of file. Wont it be faster to just directly deploy HDFS as native file system?

Comment: Not Really, a "native file system" is something that run in only one machine, and HDFS need to run at the same time in different machines. simulate a native file system and at the same time be fault tolerant and distributed is not easy and a balance is required. MapR develop its own Distributed File System that do what you are asking with some pros and some cons.

Comment: In a large deployment have  a native file system is not very useful because the data doesn't come for only one source. It is easier and more scalable that each node in hdfs be able to connect with remote systems like FTP, S3, Azure Storage, Kafka, etc. and copy de data almost directly (coordinating the process with the NameNode).

Comment: Google equivalent of HDFS (GFS) have a way to make it work as naitive FS.  Please search "Red Hat GFS" https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Global_File_System/ch-overview-GFS.html

Comment: Limited to 25 TB ? It doesn't sounds good, Isn't it ? It seems that Red Hat GFS is very different than Google option. Hadoop was designed based in Google's papers and according to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_File_System both file systems work very similar.